# Determine if a list of compare-and-swap instructions will sort a list of length N

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Say I have a list of pairs of indices in an array of length N. I want to determine if an arbitrarily sorted list is sorted after doing

```
for pair in pairs:
  if list_to_sort[pair.first] > list_to_sort[pair.second]:
    swap(
      element_a_index=pair.first,
      element_b_index=pair.second,
      list=list_to_sort
    )
```

Obviously, I could test all permutations of the N-element list. Is there a faster way? And if there is, what is it? What is it called? Is it provably the fastest solution?

Comment: Seems to me you're basically describing a bubble sort, and the number of iterations (and hence the number of elements in your list) required to bubble sort an array of a given length is well-known and easily calculated.

Comment: @HotLicks, no, often you can do with much less comparisons than the amount Bubble Sort uses. See [Algorithm::Networksort](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JGAMBLE/Algorithm-Networksort-1.30/lib/Algorithm/Networksort.pm). What I am looking for, is essentially a test mechanism for the algorithms implemented in that module.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're describing is an algorithm called a [sorting network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network).  Unfortunately, it's known that the problem of determining whether a series of swaps yields a valid sorting network is [co-NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#Complexity_of_testing_sorting_networks), meaning that unless P = NP there is no polynomial-time algorithm for checking whether your particular choice of pairs will work correctly.

Interestingly, though, you don't need to try all possible permutations of the input.  There's a result called the [zero-one principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#Zero-one_principle) that states that as long as your sorting network will correctly sort a list of 0s and 1s, it will sort any input sequence correctly.  Consequently, rather than trying all n! possible permutations of the inputs, you can check all 2<sup>n</sup> possible sequences of 0s and 1s.  This is still pretty infeasible if n is very large, but might be useful if your choice of n is small.

As for the best possible way to build a sorting network - this is an open problem!  There are many good sorting networks that run quickly on most inputs, and there are also a few sorting networks that are known to be optimal.  Searching for "optimal sorting network" might turn up some useful links.

Hope this helps!